# Make the container the right height for its content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm using Bootstrap 4 for my grid system, and I've got 2 columns below each other. My problem is that with `height: 100%` the container doesn't grow with the content.
With using `overflow: auto` it somewhat works as in the content of the columns don't overlap anymore but it gives a scrollbar, preferably I'd like the container to change height accordingly to the content.[image]

## HTML

```
<div class="py-5 container-fluid about">
    <div class="container-fluid about-wrapper-size">
    <div class="row w-100 h-100 m-0 p-0">
        <div class="align-self-center col-md-4"><img src="http://kingofwallpapers.com/square/square-009.jpg" class="rounded-circle d-block img-fluid mx-auto about-photo"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 align-self-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 about-para-wrapper">
                <h1 class="about-heading">Heading</h1>
                <hr />
                <p class="about-lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a odio tristique, tempus est quis, tempus mi. Etiam malesuada enim eget sapien faucibus, eu dictum nunc porta. In sem arcu, lacinia at justo quis, faucibus maximus enim. Donec
                    suscipit nulla arcu, vitae pulvinar enim blandit quis. Donec at neque id velit pharetra mattis. In eu facilisis sem, a rutrum tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent in bibendum velit. Nam laoreet, metus ac bibendum feugiat, orci nunc fermentum
                    lorem, nec mollis nulla dui a nisl. Sed cursus ullamcorper malesuada. Suspendisse finibus eros nec viverra mattis. Curabitur venenatis, nisi et mollis tempor, erat magna mollis mi, in rhoncus neque magna a tellus. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.vp-divider {
    background-color:#FFA366 !important;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    height:1vh;
}

.about {
    height:100%;
    background-image: url("../images/tile.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.about-photo {
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.about-heading {
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-size: 6em;
}

.about-lead {
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:300;
}

.about-para-wrapper {
    padding: 20 20 20 20;
    background-color:#EFDFCB;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 20;
    margin-bottom: 20;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(135,135,135,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(135,135,135,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 1px rgba(135,135,135,1);
}

.about-wrapper-size {
    width:100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1661px) {
    .about-wrapper-size {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .about-para-wrapper {
        margin-left: 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand, it looks all fine. https://jsfiddle.net/hkred6d7/ can you point out what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can't be replicated using the code you provided.

However, you can use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height` to make sure it goes beyond 100% if the content is long enough to require that.

> The min-height property is used to set the minimum height of a given element. It prevents the used value of the height property from becoming smaller than the value specified for min-height. The value of min-height overrides both max-height and height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, it seems like you want the 'variable width content' and should be using: col-{breakpoint}-auto.

Tested in a pen quickly, and changing this seemed to fix it.

```
<div class="col-md-auto about-para-wrapper">
```

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

edit: actually this solved issues with the heading text overflowing on the side and some weird width change when the screen size changed.

The overlap in you problem, I can only recreate it when I give the about section a height size in px. Which doesn't appear in you code.